# During MySQL dump web requests will not be delivered

Tags: mysql

when I run a MySQL dump I noticed that the webserver does not deliver any requests.
The CPU is not fully occupied.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: You might also notice that it is pretty common that a dump locks tables readonly, and that might cause a problem with running queries other than selects.  you can try `--lock-tables=false` switch and see if it changes anything

Comment: Also, using MyISAM is more problematic than InnoDB.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size and the configuration of your database this might be normal.

To prevent this you can set up a replication slave and make your dump on the slave.